# Advanced regex: What would be the regex for this pattern?

Tags: regex

Want to identify names of all authors in the following text:

```
@misc{diaz2006automatic,
  title={AUTOMATIC ROCKING DEVICE},
  author={Diaz, Navarro David and Gines, Rodriguez Noe},
  year={2006},
  month=jul # "~12",
  note={EP Patent 1,678,025}
}


@article{standefer1984sitting,
  title={The sitting position in neurosurgery: a retrospective analysis of 488 cases},
  author={Standefer, Michael and Bay, Janet W and Trusso, Russell},
  journal={Neurosurgery},
  volume={14},
  number={6},
  pages={649--658},
  year={1984},
  publisher={LWW}
}


@article{gentsch1992identification,
  title={Identification of group A rotavirus gene 4 types by polymerase chain reaction.},
  author={GenTSCH, JoN R and Glass, RI and Woods, P and Gouvea, V and Gorziglia, M and Flores, J and Das, BK and Bhan, MK},
  journal={Journal of Clinical Microbiology},
  volume={30},
  number={6},
  pages={1365--1373},
  year={1992},
  publisher={Am Soc Microbiol}
}
```

For the above text, regex should match:

> match1 - Diaz, Navarro David
>   match2 - Gines, Rodriguez Noe
>   match3 - Standefer, Michael
>   match4 - Janet W
>   match5 - Trusso, Russell

...and so on

Comment: Extract after author and then split the string by the 'and' keyword, try that and then ask where you face the problem in that, as of now this question is not according to SO standards.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am stuck with the fact that how do I select text between "author={" and "}" without including these terms themselves

Comment: I don't think you need a regex for that. Find all lines that start with `author={`. Get the string between `{` and `}` and then split it by `and`. You will get all the authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although what you want should be easily achievable by capturing the contents between `{` and `}` for all lines starting with `author=` and then just splitting it using `\s*(?:,|\band\b)\s*` regex which will give you all the author names.

But just in case, your regex engine is PCRE based, you can use this regex, whose group1 content will give you the author names like you want.

```
^\s*author={|(?!^)\G((?:(?! and|, )[^}\n])+)(?: *and *)?(?:[^\w\n]*)
```

This regex exploits [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) operator to match lines starting with `author=` and then starts matching the names which shouldn't contain `and` or `,` within it using `(?!^)\G((?:(?! and|, )[^}\n])+)(?: *and *)?(?:[^\w\n]*)` regex part

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eoz2ap/1)**